# Criteria for strict local mimimum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I read the solution from one of my exercise, and there's a point which I don't understand in the solution states that:

> > If $g: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$, $x_{0}$ is a real number such that $g'_{+}(x_{0})$ and $g'_{-}(x_{0})$ both exist and $g'_{+}(x_{0}) \gt 0$ while $g'_{-}(x_{0}) \lt 0$. Prove that $x_{0}$ is a strict local minimum of $g$.

Hope someone can help me clarify this.And by the way, if anyone know some calculus books discuss deeply about relation between differentiation and local minimum like the problem above, please tell me. Thanks so much. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition implies that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{f(x_{0}+h) - f(x_{0)}}{h} > 0$ and so in an interval of the form $(x_{0}, x_{0} + \epsilon)$ we have $f(x) > f(x_{0}) $.

Similarly in an interval of the form $(x_{0} - \epsilon, x_{0})$ we have $f(x) > f(x_{0}) $ and so $x_{0}$ is a local minimum.

Comment: I guess you wanted to write $f(x)>f(x_0)$.

Comment: Absolutely right. Thanks